# JAVA; Occasionally: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open

Tags: java, hibernate, attachment, tapestry

We are running java application on Tomcat 8.5, and occationally we get a `FileNotFoundException` - stacktrace below.

We have added the folder on exclusion list from windows defender, but with no results.

here is part of the code that we got from logs:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
                File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
                final String attachmentFileName = attachmentScan.getFileName();
                File tempFile = new File(tempDir, attachmentFileName);
log show this line ->   **fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);**
                byte[] attBytes = attachmentScan.getContent();
                fos.write(attBytes);
                fos.flush();
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
12:12:11.378 [ajp-nio-8012-exec-17] ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler - Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: D:\folder\Tomcat8\temp\document23234.pdf (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException: D:\folder\Tomcat8\temp\document23234.pdf (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1141)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3100(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1062)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1058)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.handle(ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ImmediateActionRenderResponseFilter.handle(ImmediateActionRenderResponseFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_336059259ee733.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AjaxFilter.handle(AjaxFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_336059259ee733.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.UploadExceptionFilter.handle(UploadExceptionFilter.java:75)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_336059259ee733.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$41.handle(TapestryModule.java:2475)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_336059259ee733.handle(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_336059259ee6a2.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handleComponentEvent(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:43)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handleComponentEvent(InitializeActivePageName.java:39)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_336059259ee6a4.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.tynamo.security.SecurityComponentRequestFilter.handleComponentEvent(SecurityComponentRequestFilter.java:41)
    at $ComponentRequestFilter_336059259ee6a1.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_336059259ee6a4.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_336059259ee618.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventDispatcher.dispatch(ComponentEventDispatcher.java:46)
    at $Dispatcher_336059259ee61b.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at $Dispatcher_336059259ee615.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:302)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_336059259ee616.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:902)
    at $RequestHandler_336059259ee616.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:892)
    at $RequestHandler_336059259ee616.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    at $RequestHandler_336059259ee616.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.intek.archive.services.AppModule$3.service(AppModule.java:288)
    at $RequestFilter_336059259ee611.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_336059259ee616.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_336059259ee5fb.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:253)
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration$1.call(SecurityConfiguration.java:56)
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration$1.call(SecurityConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380)
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration.service(SecurityConfiguration.java:54)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_336059259ee5fa.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5fd.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5fd.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5fd.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.tynamo.resteasy.ResteasyRequestFilter.service(ResteasyRequestFilter.java:101)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_336059259ee5f9.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5fd.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.intek.archive.ajax.AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.service(AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.java:31)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5fd.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_336059259ee5f6.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5fd.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:852)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5fd.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_336059259ee5f4.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:476)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: D:\folder\Tomcat8\temp\document23234.pdf (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1058)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.InternalComponentResourcesImpl.triggerContextEvent(InternalComponentResourcesImpl.java:303)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.advised$onAction_336059259ee6e5(Form.java:562)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form$Invocation_onAction_336059259ee6e4.proceedToAdvisedMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.LoggingAdvice.advise(LoggingAdvice.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.onAction(Form.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.dispatchComponentEvent(Form.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:940)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1117)
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException: D:\folder\Tomcat8\temp\document23234.pdf (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1141)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3100(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1062)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\folder\Tomcat8\temp\document23234.pdf (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.intek.archive.pages.input.ArchiveAnexPage.setAnexAttachment(ArchiveAnexPage.java:1003)
    at com.intek.archive.pages.input.ArchiveAnexPage.advised$onSuccess_336059259ee68b(ArchiveAnexPage.java:646)
    at com.intek.archive.pages.input.ArchiveAnexPage$Invocation_onSuccess_336059259ee68a.proceedToAdvisedMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.CommitAfterWorker$1.advise(CommitAfterWorker.java:53)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at com.intek.archive.pages.input.ArchiveAnexPage.onSuccess(ArchiveAnexPage.java)
    at com.intek.archive.pages.input.ArchiveAnexPage.dispatchComponentEvent(ArchiveAnexPage.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:932)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1117)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using different output filenames per request and check they are closed after write so you are then certain that this is error not because 2 handling threads are running at same time. Something like:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("aaa", "bbb");
byte[] attBytes = attachmentScan.getContent();
try(OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
    fos.write(attBytes);
}
```

You will of course need to clean up your temporary files at some stage when not required in your application.

Comment: we tried using different filenames per request, but we still get the same error.
The bad thing is that the error does not happen always, it just shows randomly, time by time.!

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: When is this file closed? Your code only flushes the output.

Comment: We have few lines lower
' fos.close(); '

Comment: The error implies another process / thread is accessing the file at same time so you may need to look around for a different app. Is the filename guaranteed to be unique for all VMs? Perhaps there is another component (possibly another instance of this app being run on same machine) that might be generating in same temp dir or scanning this directory for files of this name.

Comment: Also check whether you have virus scanner which opens PDFs.

Comment: Yes there is another instance that runs on the same machine that generates temp files on the same temp dir but diferent filenames.
I disabled windows built in antivirus.